# Cannot install snap because it won't accept my Ubuntu One password

Tags: password, ubuntu-one, snap

I'm trying to install Lite IDE from the Ubuntu Software Center but I cannot get past logging into Ubuntu One.

I have an Ubuntu One account. I have used it to log into one.ubuntu.com, Launchpad and this Stack Exchange. However, I cannot use it to install this snap.

I've generated and installed SSH keys.

I'm running 16.04 LTS

[image: Screenshot]

Am I missing something?  Or should I report a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an internal issue they have, your account is fine. Will be soon fixed in the next update, make sure to install it.

Comment: Do you know if there is a bug report for this? I'm curious what the issue is

Comment: Haven't seen any. The info I got was through mailing with their support, I'm sure you can ask them.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/839293 lists https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1616943