# 16.10 Cannot sign in to Ubuntu One account from Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-center, ubuntu-one, snap, 16.10

[image]
(NOTE: the e-mail in the picture isn't my actual e-mail, I replaced it for demonstrative purposes)

I was trying to install Krita (I believe the snaps package), and Ubuntu Store prompted me to log into my Ubuntu One account. When I put in my username and password, however, it keeps saying "Incorrect email or password". Yet I go to http://one.ubuntu.com or Launchpad and sign in with the same credentials, and it works fine.

Is this a bug? How can I fix this?

Using Ubuntu 16.10 x64, Unity 7.5.0, Ubuntu Software 3.20.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 ubuntu single sign on 'wrong e-mail or password'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/834331/16-04-ubuntu-single-sign-on-wrong-e-mail-or-password)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a known and reported bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1616943

you can install it manually by typing

```
sudo snap install krita
```

in the terminal.